# For some reason, despite the condition of this while loop being False, the loop is not terminating

Tags: python, while-loop

What I am trying to do is make my code re-executable by placing it all within a while loop and asking the user if they wish to continue. But, for whatever reason, despite start not being 'y', the code continues on. I tried messing around with it but nothing seems to work. Its a really simple problem but I can't put my hand on what's going on. Here is the problematic code:

```
    start = "y"
    while start == "y":
        holder = input("Create a file? (y/n): ")
        while holder != "y" and holder != "n":
            print("ERROR: Only enter 'y' or 'n'.")
            print()
            holder = input("Create a file? (y/n): ")

        start = holder
```

BTW, yes, I know I could use `break` but I just really want to know what is wrong with this.

Comment: What are you entering?

Comment: I can't reproduce this - exits the loop as soon as I enter `n`

Comment: The inner `while` condition can be simplified to `while holder not in ('y', 'n'):`

Answer (score 3):

While you don't enter "y", or "n", the code stays in the while loop. The code is perfect however. You might also be giving input typos.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler design:

```
    while True:
        doit = input("Create a file? (y/n): ")
        if doit in 'Nn':
            break
        if doit not in 'Yy':
            continue
        # Go create the file.
```

Comment: "BTW, yes, I know I could use break but I just really want to know what is wrong with this."

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.  If you have problems, it is in code you haven't shown.  If you have additional code after `start = holder`, that's going to be executed, because you didn't break the loop.

Comment: Right, but I don't understand why making start = holder when holder = 'n' shouldn't just break the loop.

Comment: The condition isn't checked until it gets back to the `while`.  It doesn't break immediately when the condition changes.  If you have more statements after setting `start`, they'll all be executed.  This is why we need `break` and `continue`.